# Getting error when calling Aurora Serverless cluster locally in container using koxudaxi/local-data-api

Tags: docker, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

When calling Data-API to a container instance using koxudaxi/local-data-api I am getting error:

```
code:'BadRequestException'
message:'Error: cluster arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:123456789012:cluster:dummy does not belong to the calling account id 'my_sso_account_id'
name:'BadRequestException'
```

Calling the Data-API to the cluster in AWS works fine when using correct arn and secret, it's only failing when calling the local container instance.